# spring kafka error handling without KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using the spring kafka in my project and have implemented a retry functionality. A message is consumed and if it fails I need to retry. Below code is working fine if I am using  and doing retry for some exceptions.

```
@Component
public class Consumer implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = { "ff808081672c17c8016730733d020001.CBS_PROFILE"})
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

        log.info("Computed ");
        throw new RuntimeException();

    }

}

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    /** handles error and recovery logic **/
    public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        
        System.out.println("Inside error handler");

        // if these exceptions occur in the consumer, record will not be retried
        List<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptionsToIgnore = List.of(JsonSchemaValidationException.class);

        // if these exceptions occur in the consumer, record will be retried
        List<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptionsToRetry = List.of(DataEngineNotAvailableException.class, ListenerExecutionFailedException.class);

        // retry twice after fixed interval of one second
        var fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(500L, 1);
        var expBackoff = new ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(2);
        expBackoff.setInitialInterval(1000L);
        var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(fixedBackOff);

        errorHandler.setRetryListeners((consumerRecord, ex, deliveryAttempt) -> {
            log.info("Failed record {} in retry listeners, Exception : {}, delivery attempt : {}", consumerRecord,
                    ex.getMessage(), deliveryAttempt);
        });

        exceptionsToIgnore.forEach(errorHandler::addNotRetryableExceptions);
        exceptionsToRetry.forEach(errorHandler::addRetryableExceptions);
        return errorHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);

        // should be equal to number of partitions
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

But I am not able to implement retry mechanism if I implement consumer like below.
Expectation is to retry the `dataProcessor.readRecord(r, consumer)` method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void onLoad() {

    configService.setConfigurations();
    
    //load consumer
    consumerRunnerV2.loadConsumers();

}


public void loadConsumers() {

    consumerServiceV2.fillConsumerMap();
    Map<String, LRConsumer> consumersMap = consumerServiceV2.getConsumersMap();

    for (Map.Entry<String, LRConsumer> consumer : consumersMap.entrySet()) {
        consumerTaskExecutor.execute(() -> runConsumer(consumer.getValue()));
    }

}


private void runConsumer(LRConsumer consumer) {

    while (true) {
    

        // to check state of consumer
        consumer = consumerServiceV2.getConsumerById(consumer.getConsumerId());

        if (consumer.getState() != ConsumerState.PAUSED) {
            
            log.info("Waiting to receive messages.");
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
            
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> r : records)
            
                //expectation is to retry this method
                dataProcessor.readRecord(r, consumer);
        }

        else {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            log.info("Consumer is in paused state.");
        }
        
        

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));`

Of course it won't work with that; you are completely bypassing the Spring code and interacting with the `KafkaConsumer` yourself.

In that case you will have to implement your own error handling.

However, you don't have to use `@KafkaListener` to use a container, you can use the container factory to create a container and use `setMessageListener` to add your listener to the container properties.

You should remove the `@KafkaListener` in that case, so the framework doesn't automatically configure a container for it.